# Powershell - How come my Ciminstance query is not working and jumping straight to Error Status 1?

Tags: powershell

Below is a block of my code where I "believe" it is failing out because it's giving me the Error Status [1] in my HTMLOutput File. I'm Fairly new to Powershell and scripting, so I'm not sure if the Query is correct.

I'm trying to query a list of computers is a Text File, to see if it has the PNPDeviceID Like 'USB\VID_0403&PID_6001%'", this will give me an idea of what computers are running those USB devices.

```
    if ($IsPhysicalMachine -eq $false)
{
    Try
    {
        if (-not ($Test))
        {   $Query = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $ComputerName -Query "Select * FROM PNPDevicID LIKE 'USB\\VID_0403&PID_6001%'" -Namespace root\CIMV2 -ErrorAction Stop   
        }
        Else
        {   $Query = Get-CimInstance -Query "Select * FROM PNPDevicID LIKE 'USB\\VID_0403&PID_6001%'" -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        
        ForEach ($Device in $Query)
        {
            $Results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                ComputerName = $ComputerName
                Active = $ComputerName.Active
                USBDevice = $ComputerName.Device
                Status = "0 - OK"
                Message = "N/A"
            }
        }
        Continue
    }
    Catch
    {
        $Results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            ComputerName = $ComputerName
            Active = "N/A"
            USBDevice = "N/A"
            Status = "1 - Error"
            Message = "Error: $($Error[0])"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: 1 - Error Error: The WS-Management service cannot process the request. The WQL query is invalid.

Comment: that's a connection error, meaning you cant connect. Is psremoting enabled?

Comment: I also see only a single `foreach` loop. I don't see you iterating through the text file to run against each computer

Comment: I've used a code similar to this one, to check monitors connected and it has worked, but this one gives two errors, depending on the hostname. This is the second error:
1 - Error Error: The WQL query is invalid.

Comment: did you run this against the same computers as you did for the other script? are the computers online?

Comment: Yes, the computers are online, and if not online, I want the Active or status to show as N/A,

Comment: Is there any way I can send the whole code your way? It's not letting me edit my original post to add the rest of the code.

Comment: yeah, my inbox is open.

Comment: I'm having troubles finding out how to PM you through StackOverFlow. I'm new to the site too. Never messaged anyone personally.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231086/abe

Comment: created a chat.

Comment: I don't have enough Reputation to chat in there. :( 

I edited my code a little and received no errors, however, it's only bringing up 4 computers out of 18, so maybe just those 4 have this device plugged in?

Comment: Without seeing the full code probably, it looks like the wql query is wrong and that's why you were getting that error.

Comment: Abe, When I get home from work (around 1130 est) I'll hop on my network and try to upload the text file. Can't access any upload sites from work.